# get text by beautifulsoup without using str.text.strip()

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to get text from a tag using beautiful soup, I try the code on my computer(running mac OSX Yosemite) and it works correctly but when I run this code on a Linux server(running Ubuntu 10.4) I get this  error:

> mtemp = div_tag.text.strip()
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

And the code is it:

```
    div_tag = soup.find('div', class_='span12 path_item')

    mtemp = div_tag.text.strip()
    print mtemp
```

I need to get text from that tag, but I don't know why the code doesn't run on the server and I have to find a way to get pure text from the tag with out using the **div_tag.text.strip()**
If it help you can see the div_tag content(text/ What I want to get from the html code) and div_tag it self here:

صفحه اصلی
        
        مکان‌ها
        
        گردشگری
        میراث فرهنگی
        کاخ موزه گلستان

```
<div class="span12 path_item">
        <a href="/" style="margin-right: 5px;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> صفحه اصلی</a>
        
        <a href="/list/show-places" id="PlaceHolderDivMainContent_MainContent_MainContent_hamgardiSiteView_NavigationBar_ASites" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>مکان‌ها</a>
        
        <a href="/list/show-places/Category-Tourism" id="PlaceHolderDivMainContent_MainContent_MainContent_hamgardiSiteView_NavigationBar_ACategory" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>گردشگری</a>
        <a href="/list/show-places/Category-Tourism/SubCategory-59" id="PlaceHolderDivMainContent_MainContent_MainContent_hamgardiSiteView_NavigationBar_ASubCategory" style="cursor:pointer"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>میراث فرهنگی</a>
        <a id="PlaceHolderDivMainContent_MainContent_MainContent_hamgardiSiteView_NavigationBar_Title"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>کاخ موزه گلستان</a>
        
    </div>
```

Comment: Class names cannot have spaces.

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Comment: @xrisk I don't know a lot about HTML ,but i copy the code exactly from the website (by inspect element) and I get the text by using that class in my computer

Comment: You are not making it clear what is the “pure text” you want. Is it the Arabic text inside the `<a>` tags?

Comment: Yes exactly that is What I want.

Comment: By the way, the text inside '<a>' tags are persian ;)

Comment: Sorry :p I am not familiar with these languages.

Comment: Hope this might be useful to somebody regarding this. http://samranga.blogspot.com/2015/08/web-scraping-beginner-python.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, your selector will not match properly with the `class_` attribute you have specified, since there are two classes assigned to the `div`.

To make BeautifulSoup match with more than one class, you need to use a CSS selector.

This code will work but I don’t like it very much, and I will improve it if something comes to mind:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
#s  = your html
soup = bs(s)
d = soup.select('div.span12.path_item')
e = bs( str(d[0]) )
for x in e.find_all('a'):
    print x.text.strip()
```

Comment: thank for your answer xrisk, but my problem is getting the text out from that div tag, with my code, the div tag was selected but I can't strip the text.

Comment: @Mehdi what exactly do you mean by “text” ?

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this error when run your code:
`  for x in d.find_all("a"):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Comment: @Mehdi wait I will fix it.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly, do you have any idea to merge all of them to one string?

Comment: @Mehdi You can declare `st = ""` before the for-loop and do `st += x.text.strip()` inside the for loop.

Comment: Yes after comment it came to my mind too.
But @xrisk your code works on my computer, but it doesn't on the server again :(

Comment: @Mehdi can you confirm that the server has bs4 installed? Is it using python2 or python3?

Comment: @Mehdi your server’s python is probably not set up correctly.

Comment: @Mehdi the exception traceback will provide some clue as to what’s going wrong.

Comment: sorry there was a little problem that failed, but now it's running on the server perfectly!
Thank you xrisk